# Time series analysis in a case study to measure gender inequality

Tags: time-series, diversity

I am working with 1 dependent variable that is gender inequality (GI) and 2 independent variables: neoliberal globalization  and patriarchy.  I am doing time series at sub national level.  One thing confusing me either I am use multi linear regression or Transfer Function model approach to predict level of gender inequality.